# Re-enabling screenshot doesn't work on android 10 with gesture navigation

Tags: java, android

I am using this approach to disable screenshot and re-enabling it

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
    super.onPause();
}
```

It is working fine on android 10 while using 3 button navigation bar, but it is not working on android 10 while using 2 button or gesture navigation bar, it shows blank white page on recent apps

[not working on gesture navigation bar screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9rRm.png)

Is there any solution ?

Comment: I do not think that you can clear `FLAG_SECURE` reliably. I am surprised that it is working to *set* it from `onResume()`. Historically, we needed to call it as the very first thing in the activity's `onCreate()` method.

Comment: @CommonsWare while using gesture navigation bar on android 10 it seems android is taking snapshot while user swipe home bar before onPause() called. Is there anyway to listen while user swipe home bar ?

Comment: No, sorry. More generally, you should not be making any assumptions regarding the exact timing of the screenshot to be used for the overview screen, as that could vary by device manufacturer.